# ¿Cómo compartir en WhatsApp una url IP?

Tags: vb.net, whatsapp, whatsapp-web

¿Cómo puedo enviar una url con IP *http://190.999.999.999:8085* y que tenga la misma funcionalidad que si enviara tipo *[www.pagina.com](http://www.pagina.com)*?

Necesito hacer esto ya que es un servidor web personal y la IP se modifica cada cierto tiempo.

Utilizo Vb.Net y el código de envío es:

```
web.Navigate("https://wa.me/send?phone=" & xxx & "&text=http://190.999.999.999:8085" & "")
```

Comment: ¿Es un ejemplo no ? ¿o esa es la ip que estás usando? Porque bajo ningún concepto esa ip es válida, y sea lo que sea que estés intentando con esa ip va a explotar. Los octetos de una ip van desde 0 hasta 255. Bajo ningún concepto puede ser 999. Y respondiendo a tu pregunta, si puedes acceder a cualquier página por su ip y puerto. Ejemplo http://142.251.34.142:80

Comment: es un ejemplo (la IP es ficticia). Se que se puede acceder de esta manera, solo que al enviar el link por mensaje a WhatsApp tenga la misma funcionalidad, que al hacerle click me redirija a la pagina Web y WhatsApp me toma el IP como un número de teléfono.

Answer (score 0):

De momento no es posible, según todas las pruebas que realicé, lograr que WhatsApp tome una IP como tal y no como un número telefónico. Intenta enviar un adjunto con un link a esa IP (puede ser un PDF o XLSX, pero PDF garantiza mas compatibilidad)